# press button on webpage -> get notification on mobile

Tags: php, android, xamarin, push-notification

I'd like to create a webpage with buttons. When I press this button my mobile phone get push notification (android, ios). Can U give me some example or google links?

Thanks,
Bence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you have to Use GCM(Google Cloud Messaging Service). Using this you can easily send notification over android device.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html 
This link will be userfull for you to implement GCM functionality